# springboot load a folder as Resource or file inside src/main/resources

Tags: spring, spring-boot

i would like to ask how to load a folder as Resource or File in SpringBoot.
Let's say i have src/main/resources/testfolder, I want to do something like:

```
File f = ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:testfolder");
```

^ But then that would fail since ResourceUtils can only load actual file(.txt, .csv etc..), not a folder.. Thank you very much in advance..

Edit:

The reason is that i need to get the absolute path of the folder..

```
File f = ResouceUtils.getFile("classpath:testfolder");
String folderpath = f.getAbsolutePath();
```

folderpath should be "/workspace/intellij/ProjectName/src/main/resource/testfolder";

Thanks

Comment: Why? What do you want to achieve.

Comment: Why? Please explain what you are trying to achieve... You need that folder for something...

Comment: @M.Deinum please see my edit. thank you

Comment: Why do you need the absolute path? You haven't answered that question.

Comment: @M.Deinum I need the absolutepath of the folder since i am doing a unit test in my project. I have a Class(Property Class) that i need to mock a method named PropertyClass::getOutputDir, Now I need to mock it and return a folderpath. that's why i need the absolutepath.

Comment: If it is a test you don't want to point to something in `src/main/resources` for that. Just use a tempdir instead and you can use the `TemporaryFolder` rule in JUnit to create a temp folder, get the path and afterwards check things in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you want to use a temporary directory for testing instead of trying to use Spring classes to obtain a path and shoehorn your test in there use the [`TemporaryFolder`](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/rules/TemporaryFolder.html) rule from JUnit.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class YourTest {

    @Rule
    private TemporaryFolder tempFolder = new TemporaryFolder();

    @Test
    public void yourTestMethod() {
        String folder = tempFolder.getRoot();
        when(yourMock.getOutputFolder()).thenReturn(folder);
        // do your thing
        // use tempFolder object to check files/read files etc.
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have any folder(for ex: config) under resource folder you should try below i mentioned

```
File file = ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:config/test.txt")
```

Read File Content

```
String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath()));
System.out.println(content);
```